# Default WinSock Protocol in VB6

Tags: networking, vb6, winsock

I have a C# based server and some VB6 clients trying to connect to.  The problem is that it seems that the clients are just randomly "missing" messages.  `myWinSock.Protocol` is never set anywhere, so whatever the default value is is what the client's WinSock will be.  If the default was UDP that would answer my question and explain the loss of packets.

Is the default protocol for VB6 WinWock `UDP` or `TCP`?

Comment: I'm pertty sure it wouldn't work at all if one side was trying to use TCP and the other side was trying to use UDP.

Comment: Try using wireshark on both ends to see what data is being sent out on the server side and what data is being received in on the client side.

Comment: @Shane Wealti, yeah I figured as much but I wanted to eliminate all potential problems that I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB6, properties of controls are set in the designer, and there's no generated property-setting code that would back up the choice made on the property sheet.

So you can't tell that by only looking at VB6 code that the IDE shows you.

What you can do is click the winsock control icon and see what properties appear in the grid.

If you want to analyze a bunch of files in this way, you can look at the raw contents of `*.frm` files, in the beginning of which you will see what properties are set for controls in the designer grid.

That said, the default protocol for winsock is TCP. But you can never know if the default setting was preserved.